# UIPageViewController setViewController causing app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion` set up in a method. Whenever the method is called it doesn't go to the next page. Instead, it goes to the UIPageViewController storyboard and then crashes. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am using [MSPageViewController](https://github.com/mindsnacks/MSPageViewController) for the pageviewcontroller, could that be it?

Heres my code:

```
UIViewController *viewcont = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewcont];

[self setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks.

There are 3 storyboards all conforming to MSPageViewControllerChild with the pageIndex property synthesized. IntroPageViewController is the first storyboard (p1).

PagingViewController.h:

```
    //
//  PagingViewController.m
//  MordechaiLevi
//
//  Created by Mordechai Levi on 4/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Mordechai Levi. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PagingViewController.h"
#import "IntroPageViewController.h"
#import "MSPageViewController.h"

@interface PagingViewController ()

@end

@implementation PagingViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

    self.device.proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;

    if (self.device.proximityMonitoringEnabled == YES) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sensorCovered) name:@"UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

    }else{

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Uh Oh!" message:@"To use this app you need a device with a proximity sensor." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Got it" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alert show];
    }

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.859 blue:0.643 alpha:1.0];

}


- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {

    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)sensorCovered {

    if (self.device.proximityState == YES) {

        IntroPageViewController *viewcont = [[IntroPageViewController alloc]init];

        NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewcont];

        [self setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];


        NSLog(@"sensor covered");

    }else{

        NSLog(@"sensor not covered");
    }
}




- (NSArray *)pageIdentifiers {

    return @[@"p1", @"p2", @"p3"];
}


@end
```

Comment: Can you add the crash log ?

Comment: @shannoga just added it to the question

Comment: Add an exceptions breakpoint and see where the crash occurs.

Comment: @LeoNatan the crash is occurring by the `NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewcont];`. I'm not sure how to fix this though. Any ideas?

Comment: None of the code you posted is related to the crash. Where do you attempt to set a property or call a method named `pageIndex`?

Comment: @rmaddy I'm using [MSPageVIewController](https://github.com/mindsnacks/MSPageViewController) to do this and from what i understand takes care of that.

Comment: You have either setup your code incorrectly or are using `MSPageViewController` incorrectly. Create a demo project where this reproduces and upload to GitHub.

Comment: The error clearly states you are trying to use `pageIndex` on a `UIPageViewController`, not an `MSPageViewController`. Perhaps you need to tell Interface Builder what your class really is.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using `MSPageViewController`, with a controller that doesn't conform to `MSPageViewControllerChild`.

From the documentation:

> Each of them [controllers] must be a class that conforms to MSPageViewControllerChild (if you don't need to add any extra functionality to it you can use MSPageViewControllerPage).

Comment: All of my pages conform to `MSPageViewControllerChild` or are using `MSPageViewCotrollerPage`. My storyboards are a mix of `MSPageViewControllerChild` and `MSPageViewCotrollerPage` could that be it. Really appreciate the answer, thanks

Comment: Are you synthesizing the `pageIndex` property?

Comment: yeah, I just changed the UIViewController in UIViewController *viewcont = [[UIViewController alloc]init]; to a class that conforms to MSPageViewControllerChild. The app doesn't crash but it doesn't go to the next page. It just goes to a blank page (from what I understand the UIPageViewController storyboard). Thanks.

Comment: any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: The crash is fixed. What you mention seems to be a different issue. Could you create a different question with more context about the code you're using to switch between pages?