# UIPageViewController crash without stack log

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

Trying to implement a `UIPageViewController`. Starting off by just adding a single `UIViewController` as a page. But the app crashes without a stack log. I'm not facing any exception as I've enabled exception breakpoints. Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018209/uipageviewcontroller-setviewcontroller-causing-app-to-crash). Doesn't seem to be solving the problem.

This is all I'm doing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataSource = self;
    self.delegate = self;

    // Get all the 3 VCs
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.matchInfoVC = [[MatchInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MatchInfoViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.matchInfoVC.index = 1;

    UIViewController *initialViewController = (UIViewController*)[self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

    [self setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark UIPageViewController Delegates
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(MatchInfoViewController *)viewController index];
    if (index == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    index--;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(MatchInfoViewController *)viewController index];
    index++;

    if (index == 2) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:{

            self.matchInfoVC.index = index;
            return self.matchInfoVC;
            break;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: So you return nil for the view controllers at index greater than 0

Comment: that's how it works. Returning nil in these methods tells the page view controller that there is no such page.

Comment: Yeah. I did the same thing in another project and it works just fine. But randomly crashing this time. Any workaround?

Comment: What is "randomly crashing" exactly? When you try to scroll to a new page? If it's more random than that it really sounds like the crashes are not related to this code at all. To isolate the cause you could temporarily replace MatchInfoViewController with a plain not subclassed UIViewController and use vc.view.tag as a replacement for vc.index. I don't think the problem is related to the code you have posted. --- I guess `self.matchInfoVC` is a `strong` property?

Comment: By "randomly crashing" I meant it crashes when I open the app itself. When I comment out the [self setViewControllers...] method, crash doesn't occur. But can't seem to find out why the crash is occurring.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem which is annoying.Have you find the solution? @Anil